# How can I dynamically map icons with values i'm getting from an array of objects from a third party API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react app which lists games from a [third party API](https://api.rawg.io/docs/).
This is my
[card component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKuB8.png)

In place of the textual names of platforms, i want to display icons of said platforms, for which I'm using [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/). How can i dynamically map platform names to an icon?
This is what i'm passing in the plat prop:

[image: this is what i'm passing in the plat prop]

I'm passing the values to my card component via props:

```
          <SearchRes 
            key={game.name} 
            title={game.name} 
            rating={game.metacritic} 
            genre={game.genres.map(genre=>genre.name+" ")} 
            imglnk={(game.background_image===null)?"":game.background_image}
            gameid={game.id}
            slug={game.slug}
            plat={game.parent_platforms}
            />
```

I've tried this, but then the question is how can I use it dynamically, as each game will have different sets of platforms:

```
<p>{platform.map(icon=>icon.platform.id===4?<FaWindows key="1"/>:null)}</p>
```

(used this snippet when i passed the whole platform array in prop)

Edit: I tried the hashmap by implementing this:

```html
const iconMap = {
        1: <FaWindows key="1"/>,
        2: <FaPlaystation key="2"/>,
        3: <FaXbox key="3"/>,
        4: <FaAppStoreIos key="4"/>,
        5: <FaApple key="5"/>,
        6: <FaLinux key="6"/>,
        7: <SiNintendoswitch key="7"/>,
        8: <FaAndroid key="8"/>
    }
const icon = iconMap[plat.platform.id] || null;
```

but i'm getting this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to keep a hash map where the key will be the platform id and the value can be the React component (icon) you want to display.

Example in code:

```
const iconMap = {
    4: <FaWindows key="1"/>,
    5: <p>Hello world</p>
}
```

Then usage can be a simple as:

```
const icon = iconMap[platform.id] || null;
return (
  <div className='icon-wrapper'>
     {icon}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: i'm getting an error saying it can't read the property id

Comment: @DooMGuy096 this would mean that plat.platform is undefined probably. Did you try to add a debugger?